# barmerge.lookahead on or off ? pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

is barmerge.lookahead effective good for strategy ??
i have strategy that give me 96% profitable with lookahead on, and 49% with lookahead off
please advise

i used this with security to avoid repainting with lookahead on

Create non-repainting security function

`rp_security(_symbol, _res, _src) => request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])`

is it recommended ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be careful using `security` and `lookahead` on historical bars because you can actually access future data which would result in unrealistic stats.

You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#understanding-lookahead) to understand how it works and [this](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/) to see how to use it properly.